# How to save docker windows images?

Tags: windows, docker, offline

I'm currently trying to install a docker image on an air-gaped Windows Server 2016 machine. I have a Windows 10 machine that's connected to the internet from which I can transfer files. However, the Windows 10 machine can't seem to connect to the Microsoft docker API (https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2) to download the files needed to create the image tar file.

Specifically, when I connect to https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/nanoserver/tags/list I see a full list of tags available for download. However, I can only connect to the "sac2016" tag. All other endpoints return a "MANIFEST_INVALID" error.

For example, on the Windows 10 machine https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/nanoserver/manifests/1709 returns:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_INVALID","message":"manifest invalid","detail":{}}]}
```

**How can I connect to the Microsoft API to download these files?** Is Microsoft restricting these files under the assumption that I'm not running the corresponding Windows version for these images? If so, is there a way around that restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if a more complete tag works.

I do manage to access https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/windows/nanoserver/manifests/1709-amd64

So 1709-amd64 instead of 1709, the latter giving "manifest unknown".

Only [images with architecture](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest/#inspect-an-images-manifest-and-get-the-osarch-info) might be defined here.

Comment: That was exactly it! Although I'm still a bit confused why Microsoft would list tags that aren't valid within their API. I don't recall this happening with any tags on https://registry-1.docker.io/v2